# WPF Hide Text Block on SelectedListBox item

Tags: wpf, xaml

How can I collapse this TextBlock (Gauge BG Color) when 'SF90' is not selected? I have tried the implementation below, but it does not work. I also need to collapse the Combo Box, but once I figure out the Text block I think I can figure the rest out.

[image]

```xml
<StackPanel Grid.Row="5" >
    <TextBlock Text="Gauge BG Color">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=OverlayPicker}" Value="SF90">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Those snippets don't allow for a proper code review, which is required to understand the context in order to make suggestions. Depending on how the data items look like it appears you want to bind to SelectedValue instead of SelectedItem. Or use `{Binding SelectedItem.PropertyNameThatReturnsSF90 ...}`. Additionally, depending on where TextBlock and ComboBox are defined Binding.ElementName may not resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on your `ListBox` and its `ItemSource`.

### Example 1

If your `ListBox` has a hard-coded `ItemSource` like below:

```xml
<ListBox x:Name="OverlayPicker">
    <ListBoxItem Content="SF90" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Camero SS (Gen 5)" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Hellcat" />
</ListBox>
```

Then you will need to point to the `SelectedItem.Content` property.

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.Content, ElementName=OverlayPicker}" Value="SF90">
```

### Example 2

If your `ListBox` is bound to an object, you will need to supply the path to the property you are checking against. In my example below, that is `SelectedItem.Name`.

```
<ListBox x:Name="OverlayPicker" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem.Name, ElementName=OverlayPicker}" Value="SF90">
```

```cs
public class Car
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Car(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

### Example 3

What you have should work if your `ItemSource` is some collection of `sting`. Using the below collection as the `ItemSource` with your code yielded the result I believe you are looking for.

```cs
public List<string> Data { get; } = new List<string>
{
    "SF90",
    "Camaro SS (Gen 5)",
    "Hellcat",

};
```

```
<ListBox x:Name="OverlayPicker" ItemsSource="{Binding Data}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

Comment: Awesome. I applied example 1 to my project and it now works. You legend. Sorry for the missing data but you seemed to figure out what I was looking for! Thank a lot.

Comment: Glad it helped! If you add your problematic data model, we might be able to get the question reopened.